# How to type check Angular Directive input assignment types in templates?

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, typechecking

I am using Angular 9 and have following Angular directive :

```
export type MyDirectiveValue = "foo"|"bar"; 
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input("myDirective") value: MyDirectiveValue;
    
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

When I use it in my template :

```
<div *myDirective="'invalid-value'">Hello</div>
```

I would have expected Ivy to detect that `invalid-value` is not assignable to type `MyDirectiveValue` but it's not, I can freely assign any value without getting any template compilation failure.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think this may help: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck check out `fullTemplateTypeCheck`

Comment: @FaustynPiechowiak `fullTemplateTypeCheck` was already set to true in my case, but the documentation was helpful as when I introduced `strictTemplates: true` it fixed my issues, thanks a lot. BTW, if you want to propose the answer, I may accept if to share some kudos ;-)

Comment: Sure. Very kind of you, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out documentation: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

Especially this part:

**[Strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode)**

> Strict mode is a superset of full mode, and is accessed by setting the `strictTemplates` flag to `true`. This flag supersedes the `fullTemplateTypeCheck` flag. In strict mode, Angular version 9 adds checks that go beyond the version 8 type-checker. Note that strict mode is only available if using Ivy.